Why does Scrimgeour still have doubts about Dumbledore?
I  am reading Chapter 7 of Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, and I don't understand why Rufus Scrimgeour seems to have doubts about Dumbledore. He died fighting against the Death Eaters, he warned the Ministry for two years about Voldemort's return, and he was right about everything. So why is Rufus still investigating, checking Dumbledore’s belongings from his will to see if there's anything dark in them?
After examining the bequeathed items, he just needed to hand them over to Harry, Ron, and Hermione, and that would be it. But why does he still interrogate them with questions like, "Was Ron close to Dumbledore? Why did he leave that specific book to Hermione...?" If Rufus hates Dumbledore and Harry, then does he even have the right to ask those questions? Harry, Ron, and Hermione just have the right not to answer that. Dumbledore can leave his whatever he wants to whomever he wants, can’t he?

Sure, but this is a powerful wizard and his only named bequests are to three of his known followers, and the items are suspicious as hell.

@Valorum they are suspicious but that is for the ultimate purpose of killing the Dark Lord which is also what the Minister of Magic wants. I think Rufus doesn't need to examine the bequests

IDK, but part of the brilliance of the whole Harry Potter series is the way in which the subject matter of the stories grows with the readers. The first book was age-appropriate for an 11-year old. Books were released every year until the last, which was age-appropriate for a 17-year old. "Philosopher's Stone" is a swash buckling contest between "good" and "evil" with a happy end. "Deathly Hallows" is dark, full of politics, and characters with all kinds of conflicting interests, some who control wealth and power, some have nothing left to lose, all struggling for their own ideals.

While I don't think this is enough for an answer, it's worth noting that Dumbledore was not always the grandfatherly old Beacon of Light (tm) he liked to portray himself as; even in his later days, he was quite manipulative in his pursuit of the Greater Good. More pertinently, Dumbledore had a very bad habit of keeping everything as close to the chest as possible.

Perhaps you are not meant to understand yet. This is a new character, a politician and maybe a bit of a bureaucrat, apparently rather suspicious. Learn what you can about him from the way he behaves, and wait to see how he behaves in future. Not all people of good will work together well, some people’s good will is tinged with ulterior motives. The world is complicated, people are complicated, J.K. Rowling is showing that.

I don't think we need to ascribe anything nefarious here to Scrimgeour. He does at this point understand Voldemort really has returned, and I believe is as anxious as anyone to see Voldemort defeated in any way possible. Up to this point he was also perfectly content the items in question were in Dumbledore's possession.
What has changed is Dumbledore is no longer alive.
While Scrimgeour is likely aware of Harry & Co's prior successes against Voldemort, my view is he ascribes this to a combination of luck and Dumbledore's guidance. With Dumbledore gone, he is no longer willing to bet on children, especially led by someone raised by muggles (not much out of blind prejudice; more the implied limited magical experience for one with that status).
With the loss of Dumbledore, Scrimgeour may be desperate and looking for a miracle among Dumbledore's bequests. Therefore if Scrimgeour determines these items can be of significant use against Voldemort, he is prepared to use his power as Minister to divert them to the Auror department instead. This is a reasonable position, given the circumstances and information available to Scrimgeour at the time.
Scrimgeour is further suspicious this may be the case because Dumbledore could have given out these items at any point while alive. Dumbledore has clearly been preparing for Voldemort's return for some time. Why leave these things in a will, as a kind of fail-safe, if they weren't important or useful for defeating Voldemort in some way?
So it's not that Scrimgeour doubts Dumbledore at all. At least, not anymore. It's that he doubts Harry. And it's even not that he doubts Harry's motives, intent, or determination. Rather, he doubts Harry's ability, at least without Dumbledore's support to back him up.
But, other than the sword, he finds the items to be mere baubles and not worth the trouble. My view is he came to believe in this interview that Dumbledore had used protective charms on the items — possibly exceptionally strong protective charms, of the kind only someone like Dumbledore could create — but nothing more, and that any such charms would only help their intended recipients. Thus it was best to let things continue as Dumbledore's will requested.

I'd go so far as to say Scrimgeour was desperate to find a miracle amongst Dumbledore's behests - a miracle that naturally he could use far better than some teens, and that those kids might not even recognize as the key to defeating the big V.

He should not douts Harry's ability because Dumbledore trust Harry, like the way the members of Order of Phoenix trusts Dumbledore for trusting Snape. He should just let Harry try killing Voldemort as Dumbledore'will because nothing to lose.

also in this chapter, Rufus and Harry are almost fighting each other with wands out. I don't understand what they are fighting for? They have a mutual enemy (Voldemort), why aren't they friends?

The idea that "the enemy of my enemy is my friend" is a logical fallacy. It only goes so far to ensure cooperation.

@Andrew I like the "desperate for a miracle" phrase and I'd like to add it to my post. But I want your permission first before I borrow your words.

Permission granted, gladly

Another reason Scrimgeour might have for not blindly trusting Dumbledore is that the latter has been visibly hiding something: he doesn’t know about the prophecy or the Horcruxes, but he knows that Dumbledore got visibly injured without ever saying what happened, and disappeared for long periods of time without explaining himself to anyone. This must have been especially distressing since the situation is so grim, with the Dark Lord getting stronger by the day, and Scrimgeour is the one who’s expected to do something about it.

To add to the fact that he finds the other items other than the sword to be mere baubles, Dumbledore essentially gave the trio a remote control light switch, a copy of the Grimm's Fairy Tales, and a specific soccer ball the size of a ball bearing. That's the sort of selection that, if a DnD party were to buy in preparation towards fighting the Big Bad of the campaign, you'd be more than a bit curious as to what they would be planning to do with them, trusting them to get the job done or not.

He doesn't have the right to do any of those things. But for the Minister of Magic rights are pretty flexible. Wizards don't seem to have the kind of belief in the rule of law that muggles often have.
We don't get to see inside Scrimgeour's mind, but he's well aware of who Harry is and the story of Harry, Ron and Hermione so far. So presumably he strongly suspects that these are in fact powerful magic items. So he's fishing for clues. Quite what he plans to do if he finds out we don't know; likely he doesn't know himself. But if he found out he might start constructing an argument like "you ought to give this to a properly qualified auror" or "your possession of this item is illegal: I hereby confiscate it".
(He might also be concerned about a curse hitting him if he fails to hand the bequests on promptly).
As it happens Harry and co are just as nonplussed as Scrimgeour, which was doubtless what Dumbledore intended.
Edit in response to comments.
Scrimgeour didn't know the content of the Prophecy, nor that Dumbledore had planned his own death. All Scrimgeour knew was that Dumbledore had got himself killed by a trusted lieutenant, so his plan must have misfired, so there was no reason to carry on following it.

Everything Dumbledore did is against Dark Lords and Death Eaters and he did it very well. The Minister of Magic also wants the Dark Lords to be dead and he must know Dumbledore was doing his best to kill the Dark Lords. So I think if I were Rufus, I would do exactly all the things Dumbledore wants in his will without questioning them or confiscating them

This answer doesn't really answer the question. It just says what Rufus is doing, not why he's doing it.

@Dat You're not Scrimgeour.  You're a reader with a far better overview of everything Dumbledore did than Scrimgeour could possibly have, and you know how the story ends. Scrimgeour cannot afford to entirely trust Dumbledore's Amazing Posthumous Secret Plan. Dumbledore could be wrong. His best might not be good enough. Something the Ministry decides to do might interfere. "Kick back and let three teenagers handle this"  is not a viable choice .

@notovny actually I don't know how the story ends. I have read to this chapter so far. If Dumbledore wants three teenagers to handle the work then just let them try, nothing to lose, as long as they don't do anything to help the Dark Lord

"Not doing anything to help the Dark Lord" is a difficult bar to measure.  If they were indeed powerful artifacts that they were going to take with them to fight him, and they (as inexperienced teens, at least in Scrimgeour's view) were very likely to get killed while doing so, then handing over the artifacts to them would be indirectly handing them to the Dark Lord.

@Dat "
Everything Dumbledore did is against Dark Lords and Death Eaters and he did it very well." Do you have any evidence for that? In the first war Dumbledore was the leader, it was almost lost before Harry's parents were killed. Now Dumbledore was killed by "I trust Snape". In the end, Harry wins despite Dumbledore's plans, not because of them.
